# is it possible to get IP address of a wifi that you are not connected to

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip-address

Just like the question states.  Is it somehow possible to get the IP address of a network that you don't have access to?  For example, if you click the little wifi button on your task bar, and highlight your cursor over one of the options, you get some info.  But your external IP address is actually the address of the router, isn't it?  Which would mean you would have to connect to the wifi, and then the router to get an IP address, correct?

I realy just want a simple answer:  `No`  or `Yes and here's how`

Comment: If you are referring to a private IP address, no - that is assigned to your computer after connection. As for the AP's public IP address, the term is somewhat ambiguous - the IP address assigned to the router might not be "public" if it is behind a switch or other network device. The information your computer displays about an AP before a connection is established is obtained from information being broadcast by the router.

Comment: If the network is properly encrypted you get nothing. Else you could potentially get anything just by sniffing (private IP is trivial with kismet, and public IP is unlikely).

Comment: Simple answers, like *Yes/No/Maybe*, are frowned upon here. People are *required* to add some short explanation, lest their posts be deleted as unhelpful.

Comment: You may learn the public IP of the network, whatever it may be, only if someone if transmitting it in plain text, which in a properly encrypted wifi network will never happen. As to the headers of frames, they never carry such info. Intruders, on the other hand, are much more interested in the LAN, private network, which you can easily identify with any sniffing tool.

Comment: A network does not have an IP address. Devices have IP addresses, so which device's IP address do you want to get?

Comment: @Thomas, your statement is wrong, a device capable to work in layer 3 or above could have an ip address or instead a layer 2 device capable to work with an especific protocol as IPv4/v6 example, cisco switchs, but some devices work in lower layers as bridges or hubs withour any posibility to have an ip address.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia: yeah, not all devices have IP addresses, but a network itself will never have. If the question would be more specific about a device, we could better explain why that particular device has no IP address.

Answer (score 5):

**No**.

And the answer is the [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). Wifi technologies, uses [IEEE 802.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#IEEE_802.11_standard) standard who works in **First** and **Second** layer in the OSI Model.

Asuming that statements, you can't get a Layer 3 protocol as [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) or [v6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) if not even reach the lower layers.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: No.

When you aren't connected you have no way of knowing what the IP is even if you create something that "remembers" the IP when you were last connected, because the IP might change every 10 seconds for all you (or your computer) knows.

**EDIT**
Your public IP is the public IP of the router. The IP of the router that your computer sees is the private IP of the router. The above explanation was written for the public IP, but the same would hold true for the private IP (though it would be much less likely to change regularly).